# I am trying to use push -u origin main but getting following error

Tags: git, github, command

```
remote: Permission to Sathwikreddygillella7327/todo.git denied to Sathwikreddygillella.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Sathwikreddygillella7327/todo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

PS C:\Users\sathw\OneDrive\Desktop\Todo>

Comment: Do you have permission to read or write the file `todo.git`?

Comment: @zois They are logged into Sathwikreddygillella without the 7327. A correct login should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently logged into Git as Sathwikreddygillella, not Sathwikreddygillella7327. Login to Sathwikreddygillella7327 instead.